Laravel middleware for every toMail notification
My application sends a lot of emails to users. Just recently, I created a new database table to add the user ids for email addresses that are bouncing or getting rejected.  Now that I am recording the bad email addresses, I want to prevent the application from attempting to send emails to these users.
Instead of checking for every single time I send a notification email, is there a way to do this only one time for all toMail() notifications?
Here is a sample Notification that sends email via toMail():
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class AlertEmailChange extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private mixed $title;
    private mixed $body;
    private mixed $url;
    private mixed $changed;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     */
    public function __construct($notification)
    {
        $this->title = $notification['title'];
        $this->body = $notification['body'];
        $this->url = $notification['url'];
        $this->changed = $notification['changed'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @return array<int, string>
     */
    public function via(object $notifiable): array
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     */
    public function toMail(object $notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject($this->title)
            ->greeting($this->title)
            ->line($this->body)
            ->salutation('Thank you');
    }

}


I asume that you send emails in a job. So you could use https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#skipping-jobs to skip the job if the user has the bounced flag.

I'm sending an email via notification, using toMail(object $notifiable): MailMessage. The class has "use Queueable".  Is there a way to override the toMail notification job? I added the notification code to the question.
